# why is terraform local-exec is taking forever to finish

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecr

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      docker build -t imagename -f devops/Dockerfile .
      aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
      docker tag imagename:latest xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest
      docker push xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest
    EOT
    working_dir = "${path.module}/.."
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_ecr_repository.example
  ]
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ... instance configuration ...
  
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.example
  ]
}
```

This is a fraction of my terraform. So basically I need to run docker build then docker push to ecr.
The aws_instance will be created after null_resource is done.

it has been running for 17mins

```bash
null_resource.example: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [2m50s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [3m0s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [4m0s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [5m0s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [6m0s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [16m51s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [17m1s elapsed]
null_resource.example: Still creating... [17m11s elapsed]
```

I run the commands in my cmder, in windows10. It works perfect. The size of image is 2.85GB it took only 3mins to build the image.
My null_resource is also depending on ecr, so when ecr is done creating the repo, its possible to docker push

if i remove null_resource, it runs perfectly, it creates ec2 and ecr.

Comment: If this is not a copy-paste error, then the space between the image name and tag might be the issue: `imagename :latest`.

Comment: @MarkoE i updated my post, its not the space

Comment: Have you tried using the docker provider for terraform instead of using the null_resource?

Comment: @MarkoE i havent, this is news to me. ill take a research. what does it do?

Comment: It does all the steps you are trying to feed to the null_resource, except the ones which use ECR. So build the image etc.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the white space in front of the closing EOT works for me.
Check the updated resource block as below:

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      docker build -t imagename -f devops/Dockerfile .
      aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
      docker tag imagename:latest xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest
      docker push xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:latest
EOT
    working_dir = "${path.module}/.."
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_ecr_repository.example
  ]
}
```